Qodana Code Coverage with pytest and Github Actions - Qodana does not show code coverage
I'm using Qodana for a project where the backend is written in Python.
I'm using GitHub Actions to interact with Qodana.
I'm trying to set up code coverage metrics in the Qodana scan report, but I'm failing to make Qodana show the code coverage or use the test results in any way.
I tried to set up everything according to
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/qodana/code-coverage.html
The only difference: I'm using pytest instead of unittest, as suggested by the GitHub Actions template. Apart from this I', trying to follow the documentation.
https://github.com/qodana/qodana-coverage/blob/7360c03be1f44a4ed0e591218977005b07dd569e/.github/workflows/python.yml
Below you can find my qodana.yaml and my GitHub Actions yaml. The Action does run, the tests are executed (GitHub Action Screenshot) and an artifact with the report in XML format is uploaded. Problem: Qodana does not seem to use the report at all (see screenshot), the Code Coverage in the top right is still set to "Not Set".
My Question: Does anybody know how I have to configure Qodana in order to display Code Coverage results? The documentation says the default profile should be fine. I have not set any other Qodana profiles, just using the default.

qodana.yaml
version: "1.0"
linter: jetbrains/qodana-python-community:2023.3
exclude:
  - name: PyShadowingNamesInspection
  - name: PyListCreationInspection
  - name: PyPep8Inspection
  - name: PyPep8NamingInspection
  - name: PyUnusedLocalInspection
  - name: PyMethodMayBeStaticInspection
  - name: PyIncorrectDocstringInspection
  - name: All
    paths:
      - path/to/excluded/folder


GitHub Action yaml
name: Qodana
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: # Specify your branches here
      - main # The 'main' branch
      - 'releases/*' # The release branches

jobs:
  qodana:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write
      checks: write
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}  # to check out the actual pull request commit, not the merge commit
          fetch-depth: 0  # a full history is required for pull request analysis
      
      - name: Set up Python 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    
      - name: Run tests with coverage
        run: |
          coverage run -m pytest -s
          coverage xml -o .qodana/code-coverage/coverage.xml

      - name: Archive coverage data
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: py-coverage-data
          path: .qodana/code-coverage

      - name: 'Qodana Scan'
        uses: JetBrains/qodana-action@v2023.3
        env:
          QODANA_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.QODANA_TOKEN }}
        with:
          args: --baseline,qodana.sarif.json

I tried to follow the Qodana documentation to set up code coverage for Python. I expected the code coverage results to show up in the report overview of the Qodana result.

The reason why it doesn't work is because the code coverage feature is available only in the paid subscription plans: Ultimate and Ultimate Plus. If you use jetbrains/qodana-python instead of jetbrains/qodana-python-community your setup should work.
